# script for changing prefix of filename in bash

Tags: bash, sed, awk

From

```
abcd_if_vb.c
abcd_if_av.c
```

to

```
edfg_if_vb.c
edfg_if_av.c
```

The problem is to catch what file have `abcd` prefix.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not really.

```
for file in abcd*
do
  mv "$file" "edfg${file#abcd}"
done
```

Comment: mv "$file" "${file/#abcd/edfg}" - much more elegant, imho!

Answer (score 6):

If you have `rename`, you can rename those files using

```
rename abcd_ edfg_ abcd*
```

Comment: Be cautious, as the usage of `rename` is system-dependent, you also have one working with regular expressions. Be sure to check `man rename` first. But `rename` is in general a good approach for these situations.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -1 abcd*|awk '{f=$0;gsub(f,"abcd","efgh");system("mv "$0" "f);}'
```